# GCDAsyncsocket broadcast to all IPs

Tags: java, ios, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to implement an IP discoverer app for microchip platform. I am using [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/tree/master/GCD/Xcode/UdpEchoClient/Mobile) to do this. IF I send a specific message, all devices of interest will respond with their network credentials.

With GCDAsyncSocket, If I use a specific IP, I can get a response. But I am not sure how to broadcast this message to all IPs in the network.

My Code:
udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

```
- (void)setupSocket
{   
    NSError *error = nil;


    if (![udpSocket bindToPort:0 error:&error])
    {
        [self logError:FORMAT(@"Error binding: %@", error)];
        return;
    }
    if (![udpSocket beginReceiving:&error])
    {
        [self logError:FORMAT(@"Error receiving: %@", error)];
        return;
    }
    [udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error];
    if (error != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error enableing broadcast: %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }

    [self logInfo:@"Ready"];
}

- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
    NSString *host = addrField.text;
    NSError *error = nil;


    NSData *data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:tag];


    [self logMessage:FORMAT(@"SENT (%i): %@", (int)tag, msg)];

    tag++;
}
```

Now, how can I make it to send to all IPs instead of only one IP? In the original PC java app, I can see something like

```
socket = new DatagramSocket(30303);
            socket.setBroadcast(true);
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255");
            packet = new DatagramPacket(str.getBytes(),
                    str.length(), address, 30303);

            socket.send(packet);
```

And I want to do the same on this app. Appreciate some help.

Comment: What was your host value?  Should it be 255.255.255.255?

Comment: Well, there are multiple host addresses. I want to broadcast to all, so that all hardware units that identify the message will respond back. My laptop which sends the udp via iphone simulator is say 192.168.2.1. Then there are multiple devices such as 192.168.2.3, 2.34,2.101, etc that I would like to get a response from. Currently, IF I specify one host address (say 192.168.2.34), I can get the response.

Comment: I based my comment on your given java code which sent a message to 255.255.255.255.  Sending a UDP datagram to this address delivers the message to any host on the local network segment.

Comment: If I use 255.255.255.255 as the host address, then I get no response.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the same socket library in my ios app for the same purpose (searching device on network)
the code i have used was..

```
_broadcastSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
if ([_broadcastSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:&error] == false) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to enable broadcast, Reason : %@",[error userInfo]);
    }
[_broadcastSocket sendData:data toHost:@"255.255.255.255" port:5944 withTimeout:-1 tag:5];
```

Calling sendata function of socket with NSData object will broadcast data to all the ip on the network listening on the given port.